# How to attach jQuery plugin to dynamically generated element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap spinedit plugin. It works fine when I attach it for any existing element

I have put below code in dom ready

```
$('.spin').spinedit({ step: 5 });
```

But this is not working for dynamically added input. I can register this every time when ever new element added in Dom. But I am looking for something like jQuery's `.on` event. So I just need to write attach plugin code once and it will work for all.

Thanks in advance.

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
        connectWith: '.sortable',
        iframeFix: false,
        items: 'div.widget',
        opacity: 0.8,
        helper: 'original',
        revert: true,
        forceHelperSize: true,
        placeholder: 'sortable-box-placeholder round-all',
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        tolerance: 'pointer'
    });
```

Comment: no magic solutions, apply plugin after insertion

Comment: And What about plugin Events ? Do i need to register as well ?

Comment: what do you mean `register events` ?

Comment: By the sounds of it the plugins creator assumed the element was in the dom, your just going to have to do it after you place the element in the dom.

Comment: @user3264939 I would hope that the plugin creator(s) handle the setup of events. As long as the element(s) are in the DOM, the plugin should set itself up when you initialize it. The trick is to insert your content into the DOM ***before*** initializing the plugin.

Comment: It's actually difficult for plugins to constantly monitor the DOM for new changes—this concept was distilled into the DOM mutations event specs, but was eventually abandoned because it is simply too costly to monitor all DOM nodes at any instances. The best way is to initialize the plugin on newly inserted elements **after** DOM insertion.

Answer (score -1):

Delegate the event to parent. Suppose you've parent with class `.parent`, you can do following in almost all event cases.

```
$('.parent').('spinedit', '.spin', { step: 5 });
```

Now even if you add more `.spin` element dynamically, everything will be assigned all JavaScript events.

read more about `on` here https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: This does not guarantee that it will work, unless the plugin triggers a custom event called "spinedit". Also, `.on()` listens to event bubbling, it does not check for DOM mutations.

Comment: That's why the most of the cases, not all. If you apply `on` on parent for every child target to consume the event, it'll handle child mutation as well. You can try with basic click event inside buttons of `div` and dynamically adding more `buttons`.

Comment: You're not getting my point—the `.on()` method **does not check for DOM mutations**. It simply listens to an event, custom or native, bubbling up from a chosen selector (if specified) from your selector. It does not dynamically bind new event handlers to newly added DOM nodes. Citing the [official docs](https://api.jquery.com/on/): "jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and **runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector.**"

Comment: I'm sorry but you're not getting my point too. See when you delegate `on` on parent to assign click to childs (for ex), then if you add child in future, it'll also register the click.

Comment: See this for example to know what I'm saying. The bottom button will add new button to div and it'll register the click immediately

http://jsbin.com/suviweneqa/1/

Comment: That only applies for "events". SpinEdit is **not an event** but a method, so I'm not sure what you're getting at. Just like how `$.filter()` and `$.ajax()` is a jQuery method, you'll never get `.on('filter')` or `.on('ajax')` to work. I know what `.on()` does. If you can show me that `.on('spinedit')` works, I'm all ears.